# Code build setting environment variables in build steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm using codebuild to build an existing project and would like to add the version number to the artifact zip name. The build number is available in source code, but I need a way to expose this to the Artifacts codebuild step.

Cut-down version of my buildspec.yaml:

```
env:
  exported-variables:
    - BUILD_VERSION
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - setx BUILD_VERSION (Get-Content -Path .\Version.txt) /M
artifacts:
  base-directory: bin\Release\Publish\
  files:
    - .\**\*
  name: myapp-$BUILD_VERSION-$(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").zip
```

Currently this outputs "mpapp--.zip" Is there any way to set the BUILD_VERSION environment variable to the value from the file?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options you can use to solve this:
1) Use the build number env var provided by CodeBuild: CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER
2) Use ‘set' to modify the variable instead of ‘setx' for the change to show effect in the current context.